# How do I print pdf report using Itext on spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pdf, printing

I've been following [this tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-web-mvc-with-pdf-view-example-using-itext-5x) step by step, but can't get it to work for some reason.

I did the steps exactly like the guide says. But when I debug it I see that the controller doesn't forward correctly:

```
return new ModelAndView("pdfView", "listBooks", listBooks);
```

I see in that line of code that: `source is not found.`

It was supposed to go to PDFBuilder class because of the properties file settings:
**EDIT1 HERE IS THE VIEWS PROPERTIES:**
    pdfView.(class) = iText.PDFBuilder

Additionally the final error is `.../pdfView.jsp not foundnull` which shouldn't even exist if I am to follow that tutorial.

**Does anyone have any suggestions?**

I have put the .properties file in the src folder as instructed.

**EDIT1:**
1) Here is my spring-mvc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="iText" />

   <bean id="viewResolver1" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="basename" value="views"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver2"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="2"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

2) Im using jetty 6.1.26 to run the app locally

3) Here is the full error:

```
2016-03-03 11:18:14.560:WARN:org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet:PWC6117: File "C:[path_to_directory]\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views\jsp\pdfView.jsp" not foundnull
```

**I should note that this is also a maven project, and that I am basically implementing this solution in to my project. I only differs from the original tutorial in the view and controller. I implemented the call from my own view and I added only this method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView downloadExcel() {
        // create some sample data
        List<Book> listBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
        listBooks.add(new Book("Spring in Action", "Craig Walls", "1935182358",
                "June 29th 2011", 31.98F));
        listBooks.add(new Book("Spring in Practice", "Willie Wheeler, Joshua White",
                "1935182056", "May 16th 2013", 31.95F));
        listBooks.add(new Book("Pro Spring 3",
                "Clarence Ho, Rob Harrop", "1430241071", "April 18th 2012", 31.85F));
        listBooks.add(new Book("Spring Integration in Action", "Mark Fisher", "1935182439",
                "September 26th 2012", 28.73F));

        // return a view which will be resolved by an excel view resolver
        return new ModelAndView("pdfView", "listBooks", listBooks);
    }
```

To my own existing controller.

**EDIT2**

Here is my spring-web-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Scan the JavaConfig -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="[package]].form.config" />

    <bean name="/welcome.htm" 
        class="[package].form.web.UserInfoController" />
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->
        <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: 1) I can't reproduce your errors. Could you post your `views.properties` and `spring-mvc.xml`. 

2) What is your Tomcat version? 

3) Post full error, that occurs when you try to open `/downloadPDF` link.

Comment: are there any other `.xml` files in your application where you declare `viewResolver` beans (with class `InternalResourceViewResolver`)? If there are such files, post them, please.

Comment: @romach I added the only other xml I have.